# how to add a variable in a dictionary with several dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, generate

I have a dictionary with several dataframes that looks like this:

```
dataframes = {'Df_20100101': DataFrame, 'Df_20100102': DataFrame, 'Df_20100103': DataFrame}
```

The keyname for each dataframe is composed by Df_ followed by the date 2010 [year], 01[month] and 01[day].

For each dataframe I want to add a new variable/column with the date [of course in the date format] that corresponds to its key.

I am kind of new learning to use dictionaries, so I would be really thankful if you can help me.

I tried with the following code, but it is pretty basic for what I want.

```
for key, val in  dataframes.items():
 val['Key']==k
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So my solution not working and need `format='%m/%d/%Y'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right start.

```py
for key, val in dataframes.items():
    *_, date = key.split("_")
    val["Date"] = pd.date_range(start=date, end=date, periods=len(val))
```

If you want to change the date format, you can do like this.

```py
for key, val in dataframes.items():
    *_, date = key.split("_")
    val["Date"] = pd.date_range(start=date, end=date, periods=len(val)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') #<==== here
```

And the [documentation about date format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

## Edit :

The aford mentioned awnser is overcomplicating as when you passs a single value in a new column assignement, pandas will automaticly fill the entire column.

See @jezrael awser.

For changing the date format with @jezrael awser, just add `format='%m/%d/%Y'`.

```py
for key, val in  dataframes.items():
    dataframes[key]['Key'] = pd.to_datetime(key.split('_')[1], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect @FlorianBernard but what does pd.range.does? Do I have to always specify it?

Comment: @AntoineFa In fact no, because when you create a new column if you pass only one value, pandas will fill the entire column with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
dataframes = {key:val.assign(Key = pd.to_datetime(key.split('_')[1]))
                          for key, val in dataframes.items()}
```

Your code should be changed for select `DataFrame` by `key`s:

```
for key, val in  dataframes.items():
    dataframes[key]['Key'] = pd.to_datetime(key.split('_')[1])
```